# How to send dummy webhook in Stripe?

Tags: stripe-payments, payment, webhooks

I'm developing app using Stripe, and wanna test using Stripe webhook.
Is there any way to generate dummy JSON data and send it using webhook?

Because I wanna test webhook of event `customer.subscription.updated`, I must mock it somehow.

Comment: Have a look at https://packagist.org/packages/teamtnt/php-stripe-webhook-tester

Answer (score 3):

There are two options here:

From the dashboard you can select your webhook endpoint and use the 'Send test webhook' button to send dummy data to the endpoint. You can select which event type to use.

[image: webhook dashboard settings view]

The other option is to use the API in [test mode](https://stripe.com/docs/testing) and create and [update](https://stripe.com/docs/api#update_subscription) a subscription. This will generate events that will then be delivered to your endpoint.